# update a variables value every 250 MS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im busy on a website for a game. I'm currently at registration. Now the point is, that we want to let players put a code in their Ingame notes, so we can verify if a account really belongs to someone.

So I wrote a PHP class that can fetch the ingame notes. Now the one thing we still have to do, is set a javascript variable with these notes. So I can search through them for the code.

What I thought of, was to do a `setInterval`, and then in that function set the variable every 250 milliseconds. It appears to be a little harder then that. My first guess is that it has some scoping issue that makes the variable unavailable from outside that `setInterval`.

This is the JS I made:

```
var mission = "";
setInterval( function() { 
    var mission = "<?php echo Core\InGame::getNotes('TestPlayer');?>";
}, 250);
$("#mission").html(mission);
```

How is it possible that such a simple piece of code doesn't work?

I made a few things sure.

- I included jQuery.
- I've put the code in a JS file, which is included.
- I have debugged the PHP code in this setting (without the setInverval).

Is there a way to make this possible?

Comment: con you just put a console inside your setInterval function to see if its invoked correctly ?

Comment: the main issue that 'mission' is defined as private variable and not visible from outside your functions scope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot execute PHP code on the client side. The way to do this would be to call the php code with ajax or [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

**myscipt.php**

```
<?php echo Core\InGame::getNotes('TestPlayer');?>
```

**myscript.js**

```
setInterval( function() { 
    $("#mission").load('myscript.php');
}, 250);
```

Note, `250 ms` is a very short interval and depending on network latency will not update every `250 ms`. Try a larger interval.

Answer (score 1):

You posted your PHP code.

This PHP, once interpreted and sent to the browser as HTML, gives something like this :

```
var mission = "";
setInterval( function() { 
    var mission = "Hello";
}, 250);
$("#mission").html(mission);
```

What is inside the setInterval won't change. It has been interpreted server-side, before being sent to the browser, and will always be "Hello". The PHP code disappears completely. So your interval works, but it sets always the same value...

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var mission = "";
setInterval( function() { 
    mission = " some string ";
    $("#mission").html(mission);
}, 250);
$("#mission").html(mission);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move the whole code inside tgrget function;

```
setInterval( function() { 
    $("#mission").html("<?php echo Core\InGame::getNotes('TestPlayer');?>");
}, 250);
```